# Intellij IDEA tells me "Compilation completed with 52 errors and 0 warnings"

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, compiler-errors

I'm totally new to programming language including Kotlin. 
Please tell me why this error happened and how can I fix this.

Thank you so much in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moOGO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sync your project files with gradle. This should reduce most of the errors. Also keep up-to-date with the updates.

Answer (score 0):

Import the gradle project, and build it, I've highlighted in the picture below, the spot to do it.

[image]